# Changing a Dashboard from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4, how to fit the partialViews inside

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I changed all the elements of my dashboard, for an example of the boostrap site itself, but after I made the change, all my partial views opening below the components of the admin screen

ScreenShot:

[image]

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
        <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">Company name</a>
            <input class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <ul class="navbar-nav px-lg-5">
            <li class="nav-item">
            </li>
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Barcos")">
                                <span data-feather="home"></span>
                                Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span data-feather="file"></span>
                                Orders
                            </a>
                        </li>           
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
 <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
    @RenderBody()
</main>
```

My Partial Example:

```
        <div style="margin-top:40px" class="jumbotron">
            <h1>EXAMPLE</h1>                               
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, the renderbody was in the wrong place.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Barcos")">
                                <span data-feather="home"></span>
                                Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <span data-feather="file"></span>
                                Orders
                            </a>
                        </li>           
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
               <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
                  @RenderBody()
               </main>
    </div>
</div>
```